# textarea Default Text is Duplicating

Tags: php, contact-form

I have created a contact form which incorporates the words "Enter Your Message" as the default for the comments area.  My code works, but there is a problem with it.

My problem is that the text "Enter your message" becomes generated twice if the user is given an error message which tells them they did not login.  You can see this in action by visiting http://themeforward.com/demo2/features/contact-form/, not filling in your info, and hitting "Email me."  I'm not sure what I have to do differently for the default text to only be generated once when

My textarea HTML:

```
<textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="20" cols="30" class="requiredField" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">
Enter your message
<?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?>
```

The PHP: http://snippi.com/s/t9c1nq7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="20" cols="30" class="requiredField" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
        }
        else {
            echo $_POST['comments'];
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Enter your message';
    }
?>
```

Comment: @DarylGill Your script outputs 'Enter your message' at any page load. When you input nothing and textarea didn't get focused, the POST request to server contains 'Enter your message' as $_POST['comments'] value. Then the phrase duplicates after validation. Sorry for my english errors if any :)

Comment: this is the correct solution, but perhaps you could explain in the future the exact resolution rather than posting just the code, and for the record. I'm not the OP

Comment: @DarylGill yes, you're right, thanks for drawing my attention.

Comment: This still produces a second "Enter your message" the markup, including your code, can be found here: http://snippi.com/s/o4fhevx and the PHP for the form here: http://snippi.com/s/t9c1nq7

Comment: @user1721634 remove the `<?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?>` from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `innerHTML` instead of `value` in your Javascript when referring to textareas.